# Пропадает звук в свернутом приложении Push Notification? (FCM)

Tags: android, android-studio, уведомления, android-notification, push-уведомления

Сделал андроид приложение c FCM.
Тестирую. Пуш уведомления приходят всегда, и при закрытой программе и при свернутой и при открытой.
Но вот со звуковое оповещение срабатывает только при открытом приложении. Кто сталкивался в чем может быть причина?

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
private static final String channelId = "default_notification_channel_id";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    //Check if the message contains data
    if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    //Check if the message contains notification

    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Mesage body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}


private void sendNotification(String body) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    //Set sound of notification
    Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId) //NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("MES")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0 /*ID of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример работающего уведомления:

```
 public void pushText(String str1,String str2){
        //String url="http://"+str2;

        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent intent=new Intent(context,WebActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT,str2);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
// оставим только самое необходимое
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
                .setContentTitle("Hodite")
                .setContentText(str1); // Текст уведомления

        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
                Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        // ставим флаг, чтобы уведомление пропало после нажатия
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify((str1+str2).hashCode(),notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

работающий код отправки Push уведомлений на PHP(звука не было пока не добавил следующее 'sound'=>'default')

```html
<?php

 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $title = $_POST['title'];
   
 $path_to_FCM = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  $server_key = 'ваш ключ сервера';
 $sql = "SELECT token FROM tokens ";
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($r);
$key=$row[0]; 

$headers = array('Authorization:key='.$server_key,
                'Content-Type:application/json'
                );
                
$field = array('to'=>$key,
                'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message,'sound'=>'default'));

$payload = json_encode($field);

$curl_session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_FCM); 
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload); 
 
 
$result = curl_exec($curl_session);

curl_close($curl_session);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```